# How to Make a call to the opendaylight controller to register us as a listener?

Tags: python, opendaylight

I am trying to develop an external application in python that uses rest API to interact with the Opendaylight controller.

How can I Make a call to the ODL to register myself as a listener for a specific type of event? what are the currently available events that ODL support?

to create a customized event, for example, the remaining BW or any other sort monitoring, can I do that externally through the rest API and my python code or I need to develop java inside the OSGi container of the controller?

Comment: I have not seen anyone developping on python for ODL. As a partial answer, [this tutorial](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL:Toaster_Step-By-Step#Listening_for_Changes) should tell you how to do it in Java, especially steps 4.3 (advertising) and 5.2 (listening).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [RESTCONF MD-SAL data change event notification subscription](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL:Restconf:Change_event_notification_subscription) functionality to register for any type of event that makes a change to a porition of the MD-SAL tree.